# Как заставить работать nodejs скрипт на web сервере?

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-сервер

Прошу прощения, потому что этот вопрос, вероятнее всего слишком глупый. Но я с этим сталкиваюсь впервые, и ваша помощь мне очень нужна чтобы я смог двигаться дальше.

У меня есть сервер на Ubuntu-18.04, там установлен node js 16 и npm.

Теперь мне нужно сделать чтобы этот скрипт https://github.com/Zibri/cloudflare-cors-anywhere работал, вот так как он работает тут [пример, не реклама](https://cdn.instanavigation.com/?https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/855176)

Подскажите пожалуйста по шагам, как этого достичь?

Я создал домен и распаковал туда архив скачанный с github

Что нужно сделать дальше?

Comment: Deploy workers: https://workers.cloudflare.com/ наверное

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно установить на сервер pm2:

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

И вызвать запуск файла:

```
pm2 start app.js
```

Вот в этой статье всё описано:
[Настройка node.js на VPS ubuntu.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru)